# Can we update solidity smart contract which is deployed in Hedera TestNet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, solidity, hedera-hashgraph

As of now I need to deploy new contract for every change in solidity. We loss all the previous data which is in old contract.
https://docs.hedera.com/guides/docs/sdks/smart-contracts/update-a-smart-contract
for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since contracts are immutable, you'll need to create a proxy contract that retains the data between deploys.

You create a contract that points to the main one and that also exposes a function that lets you change which main one it points to. See [Using the UUPS proxy pattern to upgrade smart contracts](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-uups-proxy-pattern-upgrade-smart-contracts/).